# ASP.NET sqldatasource - Is there any sql command other than select, insert, update, and delete?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

I am using total 4 stored procedure for each sql [select, insert, update, and delete] command. I want to use another stored procedure to work on my sqldatasource. Is there any way to have sql commands for my sqldatasource other than those 4 mentioned? Please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No

But you could always drop that Quick & (very) Dirty SqlDataSource and write a proper DAL

Comment: That's sad:( Does that mean I have to use SqlConnection instead in order to have more than 4 sqlcommands?

Comment: @sea: you will need an extra Command, yes. You could execute it through sqldatasource.Connection, maybe. But look at your source, do you really want all that SQL in your markup?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will just remove SQL parts in my markup and moved them over to my c# code by using SqlConnection and connection string.